# Doing extended synthetic division with more than 2 terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Divide $\ 2x^6\ $ - $\ x^5 \ $ - $\ x^4 \ $ + $\ 11x^3 \ $ - $\ 23x^2 \ $ + $\ 24x \ $ - $\ 15 \ $ by $\ 2x^2 -x + 5 \ $

I only know how to do it if there's only 1 as constant at the first term

example if it's only $\ x^2 \ $ i don't know how to do it if it's $\ 2x^2 \ $. Textbook is pretty useless coz it didn't explain anything

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_iwIL633IL633&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=long+division+polynomials+

Comment: @Belgi I need synthethic not long division sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your *only* question is how to do the division if the leading coefficient is not zero, and that you know [how to do the division](https://korlinang.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/synthetic-division-with-quadratics.pdf) if the leading coefficient is zero.

I see two ways. In your example, you can divide both the divisor and the dividend by the leading coefficient of the divisor, namely $2$. That changes your problem into dividing

$$x^6-\frac 12x^5-\frac 12x^4+\frac{11}2x^3-\frac{23}2x^2+12x-\frac{15}2$$
by
$$x^2-\frac 12x+\frac 52$$

Another way is to divide only the divisor by its leading coeffient, then do the division, then divide that quotient by the same coefficient. That changes your problem into dividing

$$2x^6-x^5-x^4+11x^3-23x^2+24x-15$$
by
$$x^2-\frac 12x+\frac 52$$

then divide the result of that calculation by $2$.

Both ways make you work with fractions rather than with just integers, but any synthetic division should be able to handle that.

Is this the kind of method you wanted?

Comment: Yes that's what it is but how do you do that in synthetic division?

Comment: @Lilly: How do I do *what* in synthetic division? Divide the long polynomial by the quadratic? That is not what you asked in your main question, but you can do a search on [synthetic division quadratic divisor](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=synthetic+division+quadratic+divisor) for that. Is that really what you are asking?